# Error: Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type.

Tags: c

```
struct t_Node
{
    Element info;
    struct t_Node* next;
};
```

I keep getting this error when i try to compile, could any one pleas explain me why, and how can I fix it?
The error appear in the code below.

```
Node* createNode(Element e)
{
    Node* node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct t_Node));
    if(node == NULL)
        return NULL;

    (*node)->info = e; // here
    (*node)->next = NULL; // and here
    return node;
};
```

Comment: could you post the definition of 'Element' too

Comment: What's `Node`? Where's the definition of `Node`?

Answer (score 2):

That error occurs when you're trying to write things into a structure that the compiler doesn't understand.

From the snippets you've shown, you've defined `t_node`, but you're using a structure in `createNode` called `Node`.

Perhaps you need to add a typedef?

```
struct t_Node
{
    Element info;
    struct t_Node* next;
};
typedef struct t_Node Node;
```

Comment: thank you!
    typedef struct t_Node* Node;
this is the problem I had

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you forgot to write here the typedef declaration (but you wrote in your code), there is another error in your syntax.

This

```
node->info = e; // here
node->next = NULL; // and here
```

and this

```
(*node).info = e; // here
(*node).next = NULL; // and here
```

are correct.

With x being a pointer:

```
x->y becomes (*x).y so it is like you have written (*(*node)).info and (*(*node)).next
```

in your code (which is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem here is that you're doing the following:

```
(*node)->info = e; // here
(*node)->next = NULL; // and here
```

where it shall be:

```
(*node).info = e;
(*node).next = NULL;
```

or

```
node->info = e;
node->next = NULL;
```

You shall take a look at how to use pointer correctly.

Also the other problem is that you're using a structure named **Node_t** and then another one **Node**.
But from your errors i bet you've already used a typedef and didn't showed it.